# Number of roots of a polynomial in respect to a variable

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Given $p(x) = x^3 - 9x + \alpha $, I need to determine the number of real roots of the equation $p(x) = 0 $ in respect to $\alpha$ parameter.

I'm really stuck on this exercise and can't see much of a path to follow.

Comment: The usual way for this kind of problem: look at variations of $p$, find its extrema, etc. Draw a few plots with various values of $\alpha$ to see where you are going.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^3-9x$. Look at its graph. How many solutions are there for $f(x)=-\alpha$?

Comment: I actually calculated $p'(x) = 0$, then $p(x)$ of those values and took them as $\alpha$ amplitude. Guess it's correct. Should I post the solution below ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the idea is to calculate the relative extremes as a first step: Let $f(x)=x^3-9x$, then $f'(x)=3x^2-9=3(x^2-3)$. So $f'(x)=0\Leftrightarrow x=\pm\sqrt 3$. Since $f''(x)=6x$, we have $f''(-\sqrt 3)<0$ (Then $f(-\sqrt 3)=6\sqrt 3$ is a relative maximum) and $f''(\sqrt 3)>0$ (Then $f(\sqrt 3)=-6\sqrt 3$ is a relative minimum). Now we see the graphic of $f$:
[image]
Then let $root(\alpha)=$ roots of the function $f$

$$
root(\alpha)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
1&,&\alpha\in (-\infty,-6\sqrt 3)\cup (6\sqrt 3,+\infty)\\
2&,&\alpha= \pm 6\sqrt 3\\
3&,&\alpha\in (-6\sqrt 3,6\sqrt 3)\\
\end{array}
\right\}
$$

Comment: Please refrain from answering low-quality questions as it's against the community effort of [enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).